# Android LiveData: How to avoid data transfer from the database when an app is re-opened from the background?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-livedata

My Android app is listening on a Firebase Database. Whenever my activity becomes inactive, I stop the listener, and when the activity becomes active again, I restart listening. This is done using LiveData and the 'onActive' and 'onInactive' methods as below:

```
@Override
protected void onActive() {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onActive");
    query.addValueEventListener(listener);
}

@Override
protected void onInactive() {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onInactive");
    query.removeEventListener(listener);
}
```

Using the debugger, I have noticed that when I press the back button and close the app, the onInactive method gets called, and the app goes in the background. When I reopen the app, by picking it among the apps that are in the background, the onActive method gets called. However, in this case, all my data is reread from the database which will consume data bandwidth.

My question is:

What is the best way to avoid the re-reading of the data every time the app is coming back from the background?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you will need to do is set a "timeout" of sorts on your LiveData so that it defers becoming inactive for as much delay as you deem appropriate.

I implemented a "[LingeringLiveData](https://github.com/CodingDoug/firebase-jetpack/blob/master/android/app/src/main/java/com/hyperaware/android/firebasejetpack/livedata/common/LingeringLiveData.kt)" superclass for exactly this situation.  You can see it in a project of mine on GitHub.  It's written in Kotlin, but you should be able to port it to Java without much trouble.

Subclasses need to provide implementations for `startLingering` and `stopLingering` that mirror what you would normally do in `onActive` and `onInactive`.

Basically, it sets up a timer to delay a call to `endLingering` after `onInactive` has been invoked, but only if `onActive` isn't invoked before that time expires.  This lets you app stop and start without losing the listener.

```
abstract class LingeringLiveData<T> : LiveData<T>() {

    companion object {
        private const val STOP_LISTENING_DELAY = 2000L
    }

    // To be fully unit-testable, this code should use an abstraction for
    // future work scheduling rather than Handler itself.
    private val handler = Handler()

    private var stopLingeringPending = false
    private val stopLingeringRunnable = StopLingeringRunnable()

    /**
     * Called during onActive, but only if it was not previously in a
     * "lingering" state.
     */
    abstract fun beginLingering()

    /**
     * Called two seconds after onInactive, but only if onActive is not
     * called during that time.
     */
    abstract fun endLingering()

    @CallSuper
    override fun onActive() {
        if (stopLingeringPending) {
            handler.removeCallbacks(stopLingeringRunnable)
        }
        else {
            beginLingering()
        }
        stopLingeringPending = false
    }

    @CallSuper
    override fun onInactive() {
        handler.postDelayed(stopLingeringRunnable, STOP_LISTENING_DELAY)
        stopLingeringPending = true
    }

    private inner class StopLingeringRunnable : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            if (stopLingeringPending) {
                stopLingeringPending = false
                endLingering()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Jetpack LiveData KTX now also offers a [liveData convenience constructor](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx#livedata) that accepts a similar timeout parameter and runs code in a coroutine. You won't be able to use at all from Java, but it's nice to know about.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to decrease data downloads in this case is to [enable disk persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-disk-persistence) in the Firebase client.

With disk persistence enabled, the Firebase client will write any data it gets from the server to a local disk cache, cleaning up older data if the cache gets too big.

When the client is restarted, the client will read the data from disk first, and then only request updates from the server using a so-called delta sync. While this delta sync still transfers data, it should typically be significantly less than the total data at the location you listen on.